# CSS Active menu

Tags: css

What would be the best way to add an active class on this css for my menu?

```
.vertical-nav{
    width:200px;
    height:auto;
    list-style:none;
    float:left;
    margin-right:40px;
}
.vertical-nav li{
    width:200px;
    height:25px;
    margin:5px;
    padding:5px;
    background-color:#666666;
    border:none;
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
}
.vertical-nav li:hover{
    background-color:#f36f25;
    color:#FFFFFF;
}
.vertical-nav li a{
    font-family:Calibri, Arial;
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#ffffff;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Comment: how you give hover effect add your active class where

Answer (score 1):

I would add it on .vertical-nav li:active {  } 
this way you can modify both the `<li>` and the `<a>` properties

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you want the 'current' list item to display,

Personally I would always apply to the class to the li, and so it would give you something like:

```
.vertical-nav li.active {
background-color:#D9A300;
}
```

and to style the link inside that you would

```
.vertical-nav li.active a {
color:#000000;
}
```

I would actually suggest using the term 'current' rather than 'active' as it is easy to misunderstand.

I may of misunderstood what you're requesting.. if i have, let me know and i will amend my answer accordingly.